# Get URL from the browser using code in android

Tags: java, android

I want to send data through URL.I've tried the below code:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/property/p.wp?p=n&refid=13&cat="+cat));    
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

when the data had been inserted into database, the browser will return something like this:

```
http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/property/p.wp?p=OK
```

to send the data through url already success but how do I get the return URL from the browser?
plus can we send picture through URL?

Comment: Like a whole picture in the form of bytes in a url string? or just a url pointing to a picture. Because a url string that contains a picture would be epic :-)

Comment: haha.maybe I need to use the post method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient), for your need for posting data on url. Also for image you should go through [this](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.in/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html).